# Azure CLI: Unable to escape pipe character (|) in Windows PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

**Scenario**

I try to create an Azure web app with Azure CLI on my windows machine. Unfortunately, I am not able to choose runtime for my webapp. When I try: `az webapp create -n name -g grop -p plan -r "DOTNETCORE|3.1"`, I am getting an error:

```
'3.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

I was trying to escape pipe with backslash `\` but it does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enclose within quotes, try this

```
az webapp create --name somename -g grop  --plan plan  --runtime='"DOTNETCORE|3.1"'
```

Answer (score 4):

Also replacing pipe `|` with colon `:` helps:

```
az webapp create --name somename -g grop  --plan plan  --runtime="DOTNETCORE:3.1"
```